# Python: Join, Strings, Iterables, and DWIM

Tags: python, list, dictionary, join, iterable

Should `join` DWIM (Do What I Mean), or are there too many possibilities, and I should just get on with all the checks?

I have a result that can be a single int, a list of ints, a string, or a list of strings. It seems I have to marshall the result into a list of stringified elements, just to pass an iterable to `join`. For obvious reasons, I also don't want a single string to get split into characters.

Here are some attempts in the interpreter:

```
%> python
Python 3.6.0 (default, Dec 11 2017, 16:14:47) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = 0
>>> ','.join(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only join an iterable
>>> x = [0, 1]
>>> ','.join(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
>>> ','.join(map(str,x))
'0,1'
>>> x = 0
>>> ','.join(map(str,x))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>> if not isinstance(x, (list, tuple)):
...     x = [x]
... 
>>> ','.join(map(str, x))
'0'
>>> x = [0, 1]
>>> ','.join(map(str, x))
'0,1'
```

So it seems the best thing to do is the last bits, namely:

```
if not isinstance(x, (list, tuple)):
    x = [x]
joined = ','.join(map(str,x))
```

I'm looking for a better way to do this, or improvements on this if this is the best approach.

*[wanders off muttering about Perl...]*

Comment: What do you mean by better? Less verbose? This looks pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: I don't think `join` should throw an exception because something isn't iterable. It should just return the value untouched, as it does for a list of 0 or 1 elements. (I can get over converting to a string, because that was a language design choice, and is common in most languages.)

Comment: On further tinkering, it seems that `join` is quite happy with a bare string (which I neglected to check). `map` doesn't seem to like it though. `map(print,0)` complains that `0` is not iterable.

Comment: @jpp: Sure, done. But the underlying issue here is that bare integers are not iterable (but I think should be), while an empty list is iterable, but I can make a similar argument that it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have isn't bad. All I can think of is explicitly checking for an iterable and using a ternary statement. In other words, only use `join` *when* you have an iterable.

```
from collections import Iterable

joined = str(x) if not isinstance(x, Iterable) else ','.join(map(str, x))
```

Comment: Nitpick: Does `hasattr(type(x), '__iter__')` work everywhere? (Or perhaps it only doesn't work on strings, which is probably what I want here.)